# A second operation started on this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In my Controller I execute another Void Function after the date saved to DB. But sometimes it's show this error :

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

...and here is a sample of my controller :

```
public ActionResult All(Chapter chapter){

    var x = db.Post.Where(p => p.PostID == chapter.PostID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (x == null){return View(chapter);}

    counter++;

    db.Chapter.Add(chapter);
    db.SaveChangesAsync();                      

    savepost(chapter.PostID, counter);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and here is the Void method:

```
public void savepost(int id,int counter)
{
    var article = db.Post.Find(id);
    article.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    article.ChapterCount = counter;

    db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How i can solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortest fix:

```
//db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

the slightly better option:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> All(Chapter chapter)
{
   ....
   await db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
   ...
}
```

You were not awaiting the call to SaveChangesAsync(), meaning it will (can) be forked off on a separate thread. And then it gives you this error, a DbContext cannot be shared beween threads.

As an exercise, you can make a similar change to the SavePost() method:

- make it an `async Task` method
- replace SaveChanges() with `await db.SaveChangesAsync()`
- await the call to SavePost()

Comment: Got this problem The property 'ChapterID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Comment: Which is totally unrelated, ask another question - and provide the relevant code there.

Comment: As a solution it works but in my controller i add multiple model to database using foreach, because the table id of Chapter is identity and given by model i got this problem .. Do you have idea how i can add multi model using for each and the important thing to get the next Id In DB since it's primary key

Comment: Well after i Left the action result as i posted and i take you advice about change the void to async task and the changed there as well the db.save to SaveChangesAsync It's works and no problem .. Thanks for all and Well Done

Comment: When you make SavePost async you have to await it, you can't do that with your original non-task All action ...

Comment: Yeah and that was my mistake ... That's make me learn how this exactly works